# jquery trigger function from onclick of one element or on keypress (enter) from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would i best trigger this function on either click from one element(button) or keypress (enter) from another (input)?

```
$('#add-tag').on("click", function() {
input = $('#input-tag').val();
if((selected === true) && (input.length > 0)) {
    $('#tag-results').append('<div class="tag"><input id="'+id+'" type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="'+input+'" />'+label+':'+input+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></div>');
    $('#search-type').html('Search by <span class="caret"></span>');
    $('#input-tag').val("").attr('placeholder', 'Select a search type...');
    $('#alert').empty();
    selected = false;
    input = null;
} else {
    if(selected === true) {
        $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Warning!</strong><small><br />Please enter your criteria.</small></div>');
    } else {
        $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Warning!</strong><small><br />Please select a search type.</small></div>');
    }
}
});
```

html:

```
<div class="input-append input-prepend">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button id="search-type" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Search by
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-name="cat" data-label="type">Property Type</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="lowprice" data-label="low price">Low Price</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="highprice" data-label="high price">High Price</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="brms" data-label="bedrooms">Bedrooms</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="bthrms" data-label="bathrooms">Bathrooms</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="city" data-label="city">City</a></li>
            <li><a data-name="zip" data-label="zip">Zip Code</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input id="input-tag" class="span4" id="appendedPrependedInput" type="text" placeholder="Select a search type..." />
    <button id="add-tag" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
<form id="search" class="form-inline" method="get" action="/property/search">
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <div id="tag-results"></div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="Search" type="submit" value="Search Properties" title="Search Properties" />
</form>
```

Basically I need this to behave so that if the input field has enter pressed or if the button is clicked, it triggers the function. I apologize for being vague before, so I am more than happy to add more detail.

Comment: That's almost a good question, except that we don't really know what you are trying to accomplish.  Trigger for what purpose?  Also, you gave us some nice JavaScript, but can you add in some html so we can run it and try it for ourselves?  I'm not sure if you have to link to the googleapi's jquery or if it inherits the one from Stack Overflow's page, but I would think you should be able to get it to work.  Also, change the title to be a bit more descriptive.  Search for click and keypress events on this site to see how other questions have asked similar questions.

Comment: Looks good now.  You already have 3 answers, so that is good.  Remember to upvote all the answers you like and choose one as the preferred one (see the help center if you need guidance on this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your code, you have an `text input` and possibly a `button` or `link`.

Then, you need to register 2 event listeners. One for the `click` event on the button element and another for the `keypress` event on the text input element.

Then, your code should look as follows:

Register click event listener

```
$('#add-tag').on("click", function() {
    processInput($('#input-tag').val());
});
```

Register keypress event listener

```
$('#input-tag').on("keypress", function(e) {

    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(code == 13) { // 13 = enter key-code        
        processInput($(this).val()); // 'this' refers to #input-tag
    }
});
```

And your handler will be like this:

```
var processInput = function(input){

    if((selected === true) && (input.length > 0)) {
        $('#tag-results').append('<div class="tag"><input id="'+id+'" type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="'+input+'" />'+label+':'+input+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></div>');
        $('#search-type').html('Search by <span class="caret"></span>');
        $('#input-tag').val("").attr('placeholder', 'Select a search type...');
        $('#alert').empty();
        selected = false;
        input = null;
    } else {
        if(selected === true) {
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Warning!</strong><small><br />Please enter your criteria.</small></div>');
        } else {
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><strong>Warning!</strong><small><br />Please select a search type.</small></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that worked well. i am new to all this and really dont quite grasp how functions work entirely. i would mind a brief explanation oi whats happening above so i dont have to ask again in the future. if you care to!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the handler in a separate, named function and call it from any number of events.

```
function handler(){
    //all of that stuff
}

$('#add-tag').on("click", handler);
$('#input-tag').on("keypress", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        handler();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple events like this

```
$(".mything").on("click keypress", function(event) {
    //snip
} ));
```

You will need to check the [`event.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to see if the key was an enter button press, and if so, proceed.

It might look something like

```
$(".mything").on("click keypress", function() {
    if (event.type == "click" || event.type == "keypress" && event.which == 13) {
        //13 is the code for enter
        //do the thing
    }
} ));
```

Comment: You're missing the `event` argument to the function.